# TeamCity treats cmdline python script parameters as python list objects

Tags: parameters, python-2.x, teamcity-10

I am running a python (2) script using the TeamCity (10.x) **command line runner**.. The **command executable** is set as:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

And the script parameters are set as:

```
./some-python-script.py --mvn_version %maven.project.version% 
--artifact_id %maven.project.artifactId%
```

When processing these dynamically generated build parameters (from the *previous* **maven runner** *build step*, in the *same* build), TeamCity treats these parameters as **list** type objects by default!

So when trying to use the maven.project.version as part of my Nexus URL, I end up with a **list** as part of the url :
https://nexus_server/nexus/service/local/repositories/myproject/content/my/maven/group/some_artifact/['2.141']

When running the same script on the Linux command line, the same parameter is treated as a string. As expected, due to (*note type **str***):

```
parser.add_argument('-mv', '--mvn_vrsn', type=str, nargs=1, \
default='2.140.0-SNAPSHOT', help='TCity: maven.project.version')
```

... I get the expected result:
https://nexus_server/nexus/service/local/repositories/myproject/content/my/maven/group/some_artifact/2.141

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by specifying a list element suffix for any TeamCity originating variables e.g.

```
mvn_vrsn[0]
```

Which will produce **2.141** as opposed to ['2.141']!

Not ideal, but it works!